# How to put letter frequency code in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, class

This is my code so far, I am uncertain of how to make it so the output is in descending order or from highest to lowest. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: PS: Unless you have to do it this way for a class, you should use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Comment: a    9802
  b    1746
  c    3000
  d    5469
  e    15395
  f    2382
  g    2943
  h    7889
  i    8633
  j    235
  k    1290
  l    5211
  m    2467
  n    8051
  o    9477
  p    1968
  q    220
  r    6610
  s    7268
  t    12200
  u    3978
  v    963
  w    2952
  x    176
  y    2584
  z    80
this is the output

Comment: Are those counts correct?  If so, I recommend you look up a bubble sort algorithm.  This will allow you to sort the list without additional complexity/technology.

Comment: I tried using Arrays.sort but when I compile, it still doesnt sort properly

Comment: That's a more advanced sorting technique.  For now, bang out the bubble sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create an `List of Object array` and after use the `Collection.sort` to sort the List of object array using the the count in descending order.

**sample:**

```
 List<Object[]> arr = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
   {
       Object obj[] = {capital[i], count[i]}; //add the capital and count to the List
       arr.add(obj);
   }

   Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
        public int compare(Object[] c1, Object[] c2) {
            return (int)c2[1] - (int)c1[1]; // will sort the count in decending order
        }
    });

   for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
       System.out.println( "CAPITAL: " + (char)arr.get(i)[0] + " "+ "COUNT: " + (int)arr.get(i)[1]); //print all the content


 }
```